# Getting Page ID in WordPress Widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the `page_ID` in WordPress widget.

But it keeps posting `int(1)`. Whatever page I go. When I fill in a string it works fine.

I have made two files. The first one is `comment.php`; the main file that loads the classes. The second one is the `my_widget.php`, where I have stored the class in.

In the `my_widget.php`. I have created a class that should return the `page_ID`

```
public function widget($args, $instance)
{
   global $post;
   var_dump($post->ID);
}
```

When I `var_dump` it, I get `int(1)` and if I `echo` it, I get `1`. It doesn't matter which page I go.

Comment: Try this and let me know https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166106/how-to-get-post-id-of-the-current-page-post-inside-a-widget

Comment: Worked Whoop whoop

Comment: Grate Enjoy You coding

Comment: you can also use get_the_ID() function to get page or post id